# How to block many run function JS

Tags: javascript

i try show some text in function after this i want to wait 3 seconds and next i want run other functions. My pseudo code is:

```
showText();
wait 3 seconds
showSecondText();
showOtherText();
```

And now i wrote:

```
function helloOnClick(){
showText();
var myVar = setInterval(function(){showSecondText(data); showOtherText(data); clearInterval(myVar); },3000);
}
```

And now is almost perfect but when i click button and run helloOnClick() many times my functions  showSecondText() will be run over and over becouse setInterval create many instance becouse clearInterval kills only one ?

How resolve this task ? I have two possibilities:
1. I can disabled button when function helloOnClick will be clicked and for end i can enabled
2. When click i can set flag on true and after finish change on false. When flag will be tru unction will not run.

What will be best choice ?

Answer (score 1):

You want `setTimeout()`, not `setInterval()`.

Interval is a loop, timeout a delay.

Comment: amm i need something like PAUSE in JS. i want show message on 3 secinds and after this time replace message for other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` and you should probably extract the showing text process in it's own function, allowing to pass in a callback when the process is completed.

E.g.

```
function helloOnClick() {
    yourButton.disabled = true;

    startShowingText(function () {
        yourButton.disabled = false;
    });
}

function startShowingText(completed) {
    showText();

    setTimeout(function () {
        showSecondText();
        showOtherText();
        completed && completed();
    }, 3000);
}
```